# Prove theorem $(\neg q \wedge p \Rightarrow q\wedge r)\wedge(\neg (\neg q \wedge p)\Rightarrow \neg q \wedge \neg r) \Rightarrow \neg p$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have tried to prove this by using the *contradiction proof*. This is what I have done:

Proof by contradiction:

$(\neg q \wedge p \Rightarrow q\wedge r)\wedge(\neg (\neg q \wedge p)\Rightarrow \neg q \wedge \neg r) \wedge p$

$\equiv \langle \texttt{Definition } \Rightarrow \rangle$

$(\neg(\neg q \wedge p) \vee (q\wedge r))\wedge(\neg (\neg q \wedge p)\Rightarrow \neg q \wedge \neg r) \wedge p$

$\equiv \langle \texttt{De Morgan} \rangle$

$((q \vee \neg p) \vee (q\wedge r))\wedge(\neg (\neg q \wedge p)\Rightarrow \neg q \wedge \neg r) \wedge p$

$\equiv \langle \texttt{Parentheses}\rangle$

$(q \vee \neg p \vee (q\wedge r))\wedge(\neg (\neg q \wedge p)\Rightarrow \neg q \wedge \neg r) \wedge p$

$\equiv \langle \texttt{Absortion} \rangle$

$(\neg p \vee q)\wedge(\neg (\neg q \wedge p)\Rightarrow \neg q \wedge \neg r) \wedge p$

$\equiv \langle \texttt{Definition} \Rightarrow\rangle$

$(\neg p \vee q)\wedge( \neg\neg (\neg q \wedge p)\vee (\neg q \wedge \neg r)) \wedge p$

$\equiv \langle \texttt{Double } \neg\rangle$

$(\neg p \vee q)\wedge((\neg q \wedge p)\vee (\neg q \wedge \neg r)) \wedge p$

I have reached this point. I need to make the expression false, but until I've been able. Can you help me some suggestion, help, tip.?

Comment: I believe that $\land$ and $\lor$ take precedence over $\Rightarrow$. So, the expression should really be interpreted as $(((\lnot q \land p) \Rightarrow (q \land r)) \land (\lnot(\lnot q \land p) \Rightarrow (\lnot q \land \lnot r))) \Rightarrow \lnot p$

Comment: @user137481, that's right; but I want to show that the expression $(\neg p \vee q) \wedge ((\neg q \wedge p) \vee (\neg q \wedge \neg r)) \wedge p$ is false.

Comment: You will not be able to prove that it is a contradiction since it is a tautology. That is, it is always true. Do you need to prove it algebraically or can you use a truth table?

Comment: @user137481, I'm performing a proof by contradiction. It results must be false if the theorem is true, and viceversa.

Comment: I have solved it. It gives false: http://es.tinypic.com/r/maci20/9, http://es.tinypic.com/r/fcnyaa/9